# Payara could not create connection with database server on localhost

Tags: mysql, server, glassfish, payara

[Payara Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5z91.png)

[Connection Pool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fb2l.png)

[Resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgLCh.png)

[Local Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCt3X.png)

```
Here's the payara log
```

https://pastebin.com/QSKEL0Kd

I have the database created on a localhost with mysql workbench with user:root and port:3306, the password is correct i checked twice also when i type localhost in does not work

Answer (score 0):

The error in the logs says:

"RAR8054: Exception while creating an unpooled [test] connection for pool [ jjakimovski ], Class name is wrong or classpath is not set for : jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root]]"

The screenshot in "Payara Error" shows that Datasource Classname is set to a class but the server complains it's set to an URL. Can you check that your configuration is saved and that the URL isn't specified in a field for a class? Can you check if `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=root` is somewhere in the domain.xml because it shouldn't be anywhere.

You can check out this guide for [Using MySQL with Payara Server](https://blog.payara.fish/using-mysql-with-payara)